# the probability that a student obtain $3n$ marks in 4 papers

Tags: combinatorics

An examination consists of 4 papers.
1st 3 papers has $n$ marks and 4th paper has $2n$ marks what is the probability that a student obtain $3n$ marks in 4 papers.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to solving:
$$a+b+c+d=3n$$
where$$a,b,c=[0,n]$$
$$d=[0,2n]$$
and then use this :[Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150285/what-will-be-total-number-of-solutions-of-abc-n)